# How can I send large files in base64 format?

Tags: java, spring, file, base64

I have a Spring & Angular application and I developed a service to **upload and download files**.

The files that will be downloaded are fetched from a folder on my server (so I will use *FTP* to put the files in the folder) then encoded in *base64* and displayed to the user.

The user can download the file and I somehow managed to let the user download large files by dividing the long *base64* string into small chuncks of **256 bytes** (I tested it locally and it works even if it's still pretty slow).

The problem is in my Spring back-end, i can't compress a *base64* string and the only way I have to display the files in my architecture is by returning *base64* strings but when it comes to large files I get the following error:

```
    Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Here's the snippet of the service I'm using to return the base64 string:

```
    @Override
    public List<FileDto> loadAll() {
        List<FileDto> files = new ArrayList<FileDto>();
        
        try {
            File folder = new File("uploads"+ File.separator +"adminfolder");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                String directory = folder.toString() + File.separator + listOfFiles[i].getName();

                String allegato = BufferedImageUtility.encodeFileToBase64Binary(directory);
                String tipoFile = BufferedImageUtility.getMimeType(directory);
                String estensione = "";
                
                files.add(new FileDto("", allegato, listOfFiles[i].getName(), tipoFile, estensione));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

And here the *encodeFileToBase64Binary()* method:

```
    public static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(String fileName) {
            String encodedString = "";
            
            try {
                File file = new File(fileName);
                byte[] bytes = loadFile(file);
                byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
                encodedString = new String(encoded,StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.debug("errore encodeFileToBase64Binary, ", e);
                throw new EFWMException(e);
            }
            
            return encodedString;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is you are doing everything in-memory instead of inflight. With this code you have about 3 copies of the file in memory (the file, base64 encoded, and a new string). which inevitably will lead to out of memory errors. But why not just directly stream the file, instead of that munging?

Comment: As I said I just can't. I already tried streaming Multipart files directly but the underlying architecture does not allow me to do so (the website will be developed and will run inside an Intranet network so there are certain standards I have to follow while developing the service).

Comment: If you cannot then you simply cannot solve this. If this is intranet you should just be able to download a file and not send base64 encoded. If not you're doomed as you need everything in memory which will eventually fail with large enough files (or smaller ones with enough concurrent requests). So I would say this architecture is flawed to begin with.

Comment: I think there's nothing to do then since I can just send base64 strings. I think we will have to lookup for an alternative solution to make it possible to upload and download files.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the whole file into memory with `loadFile(file)`, I would suggest you try to stream it into Base64.

Try this for encoding:

```
  public static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(final String fileName)
     {
        try(final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
        {
            Files.copy(Path.of(fileName), Base64.getEncoder().wrap(out));
            return out.toString(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
            logger.debug("errore encodeFileToBase64Binary, ", e);
            throw new EFWMException(e);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried doing that, I had to change the code a little bit (probably due to my Spring/Java version: https://pastebin.com/WFdvzkYN) but still getting the same errors: works fine locally, not on the server (although is noticeably faster).

Comment: This still loads everything in memory, with a bit of bad luck twice.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been pointed out in the comments, you must send the response in a streaming fashion. Here is a sample rest-controller, which you should adapt to fit your application:

```java
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Base64;

@RestController
public class RestEndpoint {

    @GetMapping("/{file-id}")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadFile(@PathVariable("file-id") String fileId) {
        // StreamingResponseBody is response type, that allows you to generate the response on the fly
        StreamingResponseBody body = response -> {
            // The Base64 encoder from the standard library allows you to wrap an output stream in orther to do encoding on the fly
            var output = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(response);
            Files.copy(Paths.get("/path/to/file"), output);
            // do not forget to flush() the output
            output.flush();
        };
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType("your-content-type")
                .body(body);

    }
}
```

Comment: Still working on it by applying your solution to my codebase, I'll eventually mark this answer as best.